Telegram stars payment invalid
I made a telegram bot integrated with mongodb to handle payments through getting telegram stars from users, but I get the error

telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: STARS_INVOICE_INVALID

What does this error mean?
from telebot import types

from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_url = 'mongodb+srv://useruser:useruser@user.wlvpzbo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=nekozu'
client = MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = client['redeem_db']
one_week_prem = db['1week_prem']
one_month_prem = db['1month_prem'] 
users_collection = db['users']

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

# Function to create a payment keyboard
def payment_keyboard():
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Pay 46 XTR", pay=True)
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Pay 276 XTR", pay=True)
    keyboard.add(button1)
    keyboard.add(button2)
    return keyboard

# Function to create a keyboard with the "Buy Premium" button
def start_keyboard():
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Buy Premium", callback_data="buy_premium")
    keyboard.add(button)
    return keyboard

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Welcome! Click the button below to purchase premium access.",
        reply_markup=start_keyboard()
    )

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "buy_premium")
def handle_buy_premium(call):
    prices = [
        types.LabeledPrice(label="1 Week Premium", amount=46),  
        types.LabeledPrice(label="1 Month Premium", amount=276) 
    ]
    bot.send_invoice(
        call.message.chat.id,
        title="Premium Access",
        description="Choose your premium plan:\n1 Week: 46 stars\n1 Month: 276 stars",
        invoice_payload="premium_purchase",
        provider_token="",  
        currency="XTR",
        prices=prices,
        reply_markup=payment_keyboard()
    )

@bot.pre_checkout_query_handler(func=lambda query: True)
def handle_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query):
    bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['successful_payment'])
def handle_successful_payment(message):
    # Get payment details
    payment_data = {
        'user_id': message.from_user.id,
        'username': message.from_user.username,
        'payment_id': message.successful_payment.provider_payment_charge_id,
        'amount': message.successful_payment.total_amount,
        'currency': message.successful_payment.currency,
        'timestamp': message.date
    }
    
    # Determine premium duration based on payment amount
    amount = message.successful_payment.total_amount
    if amount == 46:
        one_week_prem.insert_one(payment_data)
        duration = "1 week"
    else:
        one_month_prem.insert_one(payment_data)
        duration = "1 month"
    
    # Update user's premium status
    users_collection.update_one(
        {'user_id': message.from_user.id},
        {'$set': {
            'is_premium': True,
            'premium_start': message.date,
            'premium_duration': duration
        }},
        upsert=True
    )
    
    # Send confirmation message
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        f"✅ Payment of {amount} stars accepted! Your {duration} premium access has been activated.\n"
        "Enjoy your premium features! "
    )

@bot.message_handler(commands=['paysupport'])
def handle_pay_support(message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Premium purchases using Telegram stars are non-refundable. "
        "If you have any questions or issues, please contact our support."
    )

bot.polling()



Is the bot token a real one? You should probably change it since you have exposed it to the world
